# redirect method payment magento 2

Tags: redirect, payment-gateway, magento2

When the purchase order is finished the payment module must redirect to the page to process the payment but generates this error

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in /var/www/html/magento/medishop/vendor/magento/module-payment/Observer/SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

I guess magento doesn't know which payment you choose. Do you use a custom module ?

Did you check in the order if all data (payment method) was set ?